# multithreading in C: passing a structure

Tags: c, multithreading, pointers

I am learning multithreading performance in C. When I tried to write a sample code, I bumped into a problem:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int a;
    char b;
    } args;

void* some_func (void* arg)
{
    args *argsa = malloc(sizeof(args));
//copy the content of arg to argsa, 
//so changes to arg in main would not affect argsa
    *argsa = *(args*) arg; 
    int i = 10;
    for (; i > 0; i--)
    {
        usleep (1); //to give other threads chances to cut in
        printf ("This is from the thread %d\n", argsa->a);
    }
    free (argsa);
}
int main()

{
    pthread_t thread[3];
    args ss;
    int index = 0;
    ss.b = 's';
    for (; index <3 ; index++)
    {
        ss.a = index;
        if (pthread_create (thread+index, NULL, some_func, (void*)&ss ))
        {
            usleep(10);
            printf ("something is wrong creating the thread"); 
        }
    }
        pthread_join ( thread[0], NULL);
        pthread_join ( thread[1], NULL);
        pthread_join ( thread[2], NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

I know char b in the struct is useless, but I just want to practice passing a structure.
I expect the code to print out "This is from the thread x", where x is 0, 1 or 2, alternatively. However, the code currently only gives me "This is from the thread 2" 30 times. I believe there is something wrong with

```
*argsa = *(args*) arg;
```

But I can't find a way to solve this and get the desired output.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: This is unrelated to the problem but to improve your code: Why are you passing the struct as `void *` rather than `args *`? and Why are you allocating `argsa` on the heap rather than just on the stack?

Comment: @Matt Yes, I could have passed it as `args*`--I just didn't see the difference. I allocated `argsa` on heap to avoid that the 'ss' might be changed. i.e.if `args *argsa = malloc(sizeof(args));
    *argsa = *(args*) arg;` becomes `args *argsa = (args*)arg`, when `arg->a` in main changes from 0 to 1, would `argsa->a` in the first thread become 1?

Comment: To allocate `argsa` on the stack you would get this: `args argsa = *(args*)arg;` which would still copy all of the struct in the same way. Note you would have to access members of `argsa` with `args.a` rather than `argsa->a`. The reason to use `args*` instead of `void*` is for clarity that you are passing `args*`, for better type safety, and to avoid having to cast the pointer to `void*` and back.

Comment: @Matt `pthread_create` requires that the function take a `void*` argument.

Comment: @Dave Oh right, I forgot about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are passing the same pointer to all the threads.  By the time thread 0 has started, you have already incremented the value of ss.a to 1 (and then 2).

This is a bit more correct:

```
void* some_func (void* arg)
{
    args *argsa = (args*)arg;
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        usleep (1); //to give other threads chances to cut in
        printf ("This is from the thread %d\n", argsa->a);
    }
}
int main()
{
    pthread_t thread[3];
    args ss[3];
    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < 3; index++)
    {
        ss[index].a = index;

        if (pthread_create(&thread[index], NULL, some_func, &ss[index] ))
        {
            printf ("something is wrong creating the thread"); 
        }
    }
    pthread_join ( thread[0], NULL);
    pthread_join ( thread[1], NULL);
    pthread_join ( thread[2], NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This is a bad solution. malloc is already being used presumably with the intent of making a copy of the argument, why continue to copy the reference that is also being used by different threads?

Comment: You make a good point. But solving the data copy wasn't the issue I was trying to solve for him.  A truly correct solution would involve having main "wait" for each thread to copy the data prior to continuing. (A sleep statement to wait for the data to be copied is BAD).  You would need a proper signaling technique - beyond the scope of the question). But since pthread_join is called inside main, you are guaranteed that the lifetime of ss[index] won't fall of the stack before thread exits. So the solution above is safe, so long as as args doesn't fall off the stack.

Comment: pardon me, I missed your array in main, that's better

Comment: Thanks, selbie. That works. But as you mentioned, it does not actually solve the data copy issue since several structs have to be created. What is the right way to do that? Pardon me, but I have no clue.

Comment: +1 for the correct diagnosis of the problem.  The solution with a separate structure for each thread is correct and works without thread synchronization functions.  If a single structure must be used, then the solution will ensure that the created threads and the main thread have mutually exclusive access to the data structure.

Comment: @AoZ - There are two ways to solve the data copy problem.  1. malloc and initialize a copy of your args BEFORE calling pthread_create and pass the new instance as the args param into pthread_create.  free() the instance after pthread_join.  OR 2. Use a mutex+conditional variable to wait for the thread to finish initializing (e.g. copy the args).  I've provided an example of how to do this here: http://ideone.com/Sgkeb

Answer (score 2):

The pattern to use to solve this kind of problem is as follows:

1. Create a structure that will hold the parameters you want to pass to the thread.
2. Allocate such a structure with `malloc`.
3. Fill in the structure.
4. Pass the pointer to the structure to the thread.
5. When the thread is finished with the structure, the thread frees it.

This assumes you don't need to get any information back from the thread. If you do, you can change it so that the code that joins the thread frees the structure. That allows the structure to hold a reply as well -- you join the thread, read the response information, and then free the structure.

No special locking or synchronization is required because while the newly-created thread exists, it is the only thread that touches the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry guys, but I was trying to solve the same issue and I don't think a proper answer was given yet, in order to solve the problem. I tried this on my own and I came up with the following code. Now, I compiled and run it and it pretty worked as I expected, still I not that confident that the "lock in main and unlock in child process" is the most elegant solution, so I'd like to know what you think about it. Thank you very much in advance for any clarification.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct{
    int a;
    char b;
    } args;

pthread_mutex_t lock;

void* some_func (void *arg) {
    args argsa = *(args*)arg;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    printf ("This is from the thread %d\n", argsa.a);
}

int main() {
    pthread_t thread[10];
    args ss;
    int i, index=0;
    ss.b = 's';

    if (pthread_mutex_init(&lock, NULL) != 0) {
        printf("\n mutex init failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (index = 0; index < 10 ; index++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        ss.a = index;
        printf("index=%d, ", ss.a);
        if (pthread_create (thread+index, NULL, some_func, (void*)&ss ))
        {
            usleep(10);
            printf ("something is wrong creating the thread"); 
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        pthread_join ( thread[0], NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
#./program
index=0, This is from the thread 0
index=1, This is from the thread 1
index=2, This is from the thread 2
index=3, This is from the thread 3
index=4, This is from the thread 4
index=5, This is from the thread 5
index=6, This is from the thread 6
index=7, This is from the thread 7
index=8, This is from the thread 8
index=9, This is from the thread 9
```